# Css grid system inline-block

Tags: html, css, sass

I created a grid system using sass, but I have an inline-block issue with the latest div, and I can not find the solution.

PROBLEM IMAGE
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6jyD.jpg

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/sukruemanet/zfoeuhr3/1/)`Html`

Comment: Although you've provided links to code and an image, for the convenience of potential answerers, could you edit your post to embed the image (there's a button in the toolbar above the editing pane), and include the relevant code as a snippet? The less work we have to do to trace your problem, the better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your issue.

**CSS:**

```
   .row .col.col-12 {
        width: calc((100% / 12) * 12);
        display: inline-flex;
    }
```

[image: There you go]

Comment: Thank you, partially resolved but now is not responsive compatible with display: flex @media screen codes do not match, width: 100% problems